# Using mongoose Collection ref for 2 different collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, i'm creating a simple post system in my website with a report system with it, here's my report collection:

```
var ReportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    creator: {
       type: ObjectId,
       ref: 'User',
       required: true
    },
    owner: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post', //Here is my problem
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

My problem is: The Report collection should work for post reports(like in the schema above) but i want also to work with comment report (with the collection Comment i have). Is there a way to use 'ref' to 2 different types of collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget Mongoose and Mongo don't enforce any notion of referential integrity on ref fields. They are there to support .populate() queries that fetch dependent objects.

If you want to use the same schema for both types of report entities I'd just leave off the ref and add another field to use as a discriminator.

Answer (score 1):

You would either need to collapse your two collections into one and add something like a `type` attribute for the reports or introduce a new ref attribute for your Schema above to have one for comments and one for post. Mongoose doesn't have a way to reference 2 collections from one attribute.